# How to build a sub project at a muti project

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, buildpath

I'm learning buildpack right now.
I try to build a sub project at a muti project , my project like

settings.gradle

```
include 'subProject1'
include 'subProject2'
```

build.gradle   in  root

```
plugins {
  id 'org.gradle.sample.hello' version '1.0.0' apply false
  id 'org.gradle.sample.goodbye' version '1.0.0' apply false
}
```

subProject1/build.gradle

```
plugins {
 id 'org.gradle.sample.goodbye'
}
```

when i run

```
pack build sample_hello --builder paketobuildpacks/builder:base --path subProject1/ ...
```

error occurred：

```
   * Where:
   Build file '/workspace/build.gradle' line: 2

   * What went wrong:
   Error resolving plugin [id: 'org.gradle.sample.goodbye'].
   > java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
```

It seems can't get the version of plugin ['org.gradle.sample.goodbye']

How can i build the single image with my subProject?

Comment: I got it ! Just `--env BP_GRADLE_BUILT_MODULE=ucenter-module-bucket-service`

Comment: see `https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/gradle`